# fail to check condition on data-dismiss bootstrap modal dialog

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, marionette

I am using Backbone.Marionette's ItemView to construct a modal dialog view which containing a form for user to fill up. What I failed to achieve is how to check condition before it close. Here is the structure I've been using

```
define(function (require) {

    "use strict";

    var Marionette = require('backbone.marionette'),
        tpl        = require('text!tpl/ViewPlan/Calibration.html');

    return Marionette.ItemView.extend({

        tagName: 'div',
        template: _.template(tpl),
        className: 'modal fade',
        onRender: function () {
            this.$el.prop('tabindex', '-1');
            this.$el.prop('role','dialog');
            this.$el.prop('aria-labelledby','myModalLabel');
            this.$el.prop('aria-hidden','true').modal({keyboard: false, backdrop: "static"});           
        },
        events: {            
            'click .close' : 'onDestroy',
            'hide.bs.modal' : '_destroying',
            'hidden.bs.modal' : 'onDestroy'
        },
        _destroying: function (e) {
            var a = this.ask();         
            if(!a) {
                e.preventDefault();             
            } else {                
                this.onDestroy();
            }
        },
        onDestroy: function () {
            if(this.$el.is(':visible')) {
                this.$el.modal('hide');
            } else {            
                Marionette.ItemView.prototype.destroy.apply(this, arguments);
            }
        },
        ask: function () {
            return confirm("Are you sure to cancel this operation and undo?");
        }
    });
});
```

The code is in file named modal.js which using requireJs. Recently upgraded the Backbone and Marionette library to newest version and I found no problems. I just want to ask simple question wether user has complete its action or not But don't know what is wrong with my code above

Comment: Does the `hide.bs.modal` event not get triggered? What happens if you try to bind it yourself in the `onRender` function?

this.$el.on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  alert('Hello')
})

Comment: it triggered. But somehow I am not sure how `this.ask` would not be triggered where it should ask user. the `hidden.bs.modal` works as expected

Comment: What is `this` in the context of the `_destroying` method? Does `this` contain a reference to the `ask` method?

Comment: i did tried to use `_.bindAll()` to `this.ask` and `_destroying`. And confuse why it's not working